# How to add a space at the end of a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string

I am writing a program which creates a slanted d based off of user input. 
The program asks for the number of rows and produces the output accordingly.
If the user enters in 5 it should produce an output of:

```
d
 d
  d
   d
```

My actual output is:

```
d
d
d
d
```

Here is my Javascript code:

```
spaceArray = []; 
space = ' '; 
spaceMain = ' ';


function processingFunction(rows){ //passes the input as variable rows
    var spaceCounter = 0;          
    var counter = 0;               

    while (counter<rows){    
        while (spaceCounter<counter){ 
            spaceMain = spaceMain + space;  //adds a space before the d
            spaceCounter++;         
        }
        counter++; 
        spaceCounter=0; 
        spaceArray.push(spaceMain);  //adds spaceMain to the end of spaceArray
        spaceMain = ' '; 
    }

    for (i = 0; i<rows; i++){
        d = spaceArray[i]+"d<br>";
        document.getElementById("outputNumber1").innerHTML += d;                                                                                                   
    }

}
```

When I replace the space variable string from ' ' to '-' it seems to work with an output of:

```
d
-d
--d
---d
```

I am not sure what I need to change to get the above output but with spaces instead of dashes.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
    body{background-color: green;} 

</style>

<body>
    <center><h2>Slanted d</h2></center>
    <h3>Input the number of rows you would like your slanted d to be in the input text box</h3>
    <input type="text" id="inputNumber"></input> 
    <button type="button" onclick="processingFunction(document.getElementById('inputNumber').value)">Create slanted d</button> 
    <br><br>
    <output type="text" id="outputNumber1"></output>

<script src="slantedDJS.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a really good question on which many are stuck. an up-vote for that.

Comment: Don't exactly know your reasoning for this task but to me it seems more elegant if you create an element per line and position them by CSS properties like `position`, `left`, `margin`, `padding`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the browser will collapse all spaces into a single space.

One solution is to use the `<pre>` element for the output instead. Like this:

```html
<pre type="text" id="outputNumber1"></pre>
```

`<pre>` shows pre-formatted text. So the output is displayed with all spaces and newlines preserved.

If you don't want to change the element type, you can add the CSS declaration `white-space:pre` to the element to achieve the same result as above. Like this:

```html
<output type="text" id="outputNumber1" style="white-space:pre;"></output>
```

or you can set it separately in your `<style>` block like this:

```html
<style>
    body{background-color: green;} 
    #outputNumber1{white-space:pre;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

In place of spaces use the html code `&nbsp;` your code will start working, because by default the browser accepts only a single space no matter how many you give.
Example:

```
space = '&nbsp;';
```

Comment: The browser will *accept* as many spaces as you give it, but it will condense a sequence of whitespace into a single white-disce.

Comment: Exactly this is what i wanted to say

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&nbsp` which stands for No-break space In the html language.

Answer (score 1):

use `nbsp` this add a non breaking space to your html.